# How can I combine multiple operator statements into one statement in PHP?

Tags: php

For example, I've always did something like `if($word=='hi' || $word=='test' || $word=='blah'...`
This can become quite long. If there a simple way to combine these statements into one statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think of is using `in_array()`:

```
$possible = array('hi', 'test', 'blah');
if (in_array($word, $possible)) { ...
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is: you can create an array of strings

```
$words = array('hi', 'test', 'blah');
```

and then do

```
if (array_search($word, $words) !== false) do smth.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple exclusive conditions like that, `switch` syntax is pretty clean:

```
switch ($word) {
    case 'hi':
    case 'test':
    case 'blah':
        // Do something useful.
        break;

    // other conditions...

    default:
}
```